# List/database of organizations

Tags: data-request, opencorporates

Is there a list/database of corporations/organizations in the world or in the US? I saw [opencorporates](https://opencorporates.com/info/using_our_data) but it is paid and not free. Wondering if there is something freely available.

Comment: Please define *corporations/organizations*. What data do you want - probably not the shoe sizes of the employees ;-). How much, in what format? Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Comment: Typically I'd agree, but considering they want an open version of open corporates, thats enough information for me.